# Changes required in the database when moving magento site to another domain

Tags: magento-1.6

Please tell me, in database where i have to change domain when i m moving my Magento website to any other domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table you are looking for is `core_config_data`

And the two paths you are looking for are:

- `web/unsecure/base_url`    - (unsecure i.e. http://)
- `web/secure/base_url`      - (secure i.e. https://)

Assuming you have a single store, you can use the following query..

```
update core_config_data set value = 'YOUR_UNSECURE_BASE_URL_HERE' where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
update core_config_data set value = 'YOUR_SECURE_BASE_URL_HERE' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Finally, clear the var/cache directory

Answer (score 1):

Make changes in the core_config_data table.

Set value of web/unsecure/base_url to http://"your website name" 
Set value of web/secure/base_url to http://"your website name"

Also you make manual changes in the admin panel(just to confirm about your changes).
Go to System->Configuration-> Web -> Unsecure -> 
Base URL :  http://"your website name"  and

System->Configuration-> Web -> secure -> 
Base URL :  http://"your website name"